# Sprite Kit Particle Emitter Shape

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit, skemitternode

How can a particle emitter be set to produce shapes (solid shapes/Core Graphics?), instead of texture images (png)?

In the documentation [Manipulating the Particle Emitter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-particle_emitter/ManipulatingtheParticleEmitter/ManipulatingtheParticleEmitter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013297-CH2-SW1), it looks like only a texture image can be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a `SKTexture` can be used, but that doesn't stop you from using `SKShapeNode` to create shapes and then create a `SKTexture` of that shape via the `SKView` method `textureFromNode:`.